# Make the scrollable text not visible under pinned content

Tags: css, scrollmagic

I am using Scroll Magic to scroll content and to pin a portion of the content. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div style="height:400px;">
    </div>
    <div id="trigger1" style="min-height: 1px"></div>
    <div id="pin" style="font-size: 30px; color: #fff;text-align:center;padding:30px 0;">
      This is header
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <p class="text">
       Lorem Ipsum is simply ....
    </p>
    <p class="text">
       Lorem Ipsum is simply ....
    </p>
    <p class="text">
       Lorem Ipsum is simply ....
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is Javascript:

```
      $(function () { 
           var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
                globalSceneOptions: {
                    triggerHook: 'onLeave'
                }
            });
            var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger1"})
                    .setPin("#pin")
                    .addTo(controller);
      });
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mddc/93sagkab/27/

When '.text' moves up beneath `#pin` content, you can see it. How can I use CSS to make `.text` not visible when it is under `#pin`? I need to maintain the current design, which shows the mountain as the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe add a class to the `.text` element as part of the scene. Like this:

```
 var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger1"})
                    .setPin("#pin")
                    .setClassToggle(".text", "fade") //Add a class called "fade"
                    .addTo(controller);
```

Then define a `transition` in css on the `.text` element.

```
.text {
  height: 1000px;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-out; //Add this
}
```

Then define the `.fade` style:

```
.text.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93sagkab/24/).

Comment: thanks for helping me! this is not going to work well. I used one paragraph as an example. Sorry for being too simplistic. I actually have multiple paragraphs, and they disappear all together. I hope to have them disappear one by one. Please see this link: https://jsfiddle.net/mddc/93sagkab/25/

Comment: Would something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/93sagkab/28/) work? I think maybe it needs some tweaking, but the idea might be good. Just loop through the elements nested in `.text` and add them to the controller with an offset.

Comment: Hello zgood, thanks so much for your follow up!!! I copied your idea and got it working. Best.